# Двоеточие в предложении "У нас теперь не осталось ни консервов, ни крупы, ни вяленого мяса: все это прошло на дно реки вместе с рюкзаком"

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие

> У нас теперь не осталось ни консервов, ни крупы, ни вяленого мяса: все это прошло на дно реки вместе с рюкзаком.

Как объяснить постановку двоеточия в данном предложении?

Comment: Прошло или пошло?

Answer (score 2):

Вам хочется поставить **тире**, как ставим его после однородных членов перед обобщающим словом? Но так мы поступаем, **если и однородные члены, и обобщающее слово находятся в составе одного и того же простого предложения**. 
У нас ряд однородных членов находится в первом простом предложении, а  обобщающее слово - во втором. 
 Это бессоюзное **сложное** предложение, вторая часть указывает причину того, о чём говорится в первой. В этом случае после первой части  ставится двоеточие.

Answer (score 2):

Двоеточие в бессоюзном сложном предложении ставится в том случае, если вторая часть указывает основание, причину того, о чём говорится в первой части (между обеими частями можно вставить союз потому что).

Answer (score 1):

Вторая часть предложения является пояснением к первой — почему именно у них не осталось еды